# super+space alternates modifier key and typing a space

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, tilda

In Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon I have a program called "tilda" which is a drop-down terminal with a keyboard shortcut to show/hide it. If I set this shortcut to Super+Space, it only works every other time. So it will type a space, then work as a modifier, then type a space, then work as a modifier again. If I use Ctrl+Space instead, it works as a modifier every time. Is there something special about the Super key that leads to this behavior?